# How to call field names in Postgresql database that have special characters?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

Can anyone advise me as to how to handle field names in a postgres database that have characters such as '/'. My database has a field (column header) called CD/CSD and when I try to run a query on that field I just get error messages. Also, if I put single quotes around the name, I don't get an error message but nothing is returned when I run my query.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is what my code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine # database connection
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:xxxxx@localhost:xxx/My_Database')
province_selected = raw_input("Type name of province desired: ")
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM my_table Where CD/CSD=%s", engine, params=(province_selected,))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, if I put single quotes around the name, I don't get an error message but nothing is returned when I run my query.

Single quotes in SQL signify a string.  When you say,

```
Where 'CD/CSD'=%s
```

you mean that `%s` is, literally, the 6-character string *CD/CSD*.

I'm not sure about Postgres, but I bet it honors the SQL standard for quoting an *identifier*, which is what a column name is.  Namely (and a little oddly, but this is SQL), identifiers are quoted with double-quotes.  And, yea, that is why Python has triple quotes:

```
df = pd.read_sql('''SELECT * FROM my_table Where "CD/CSD"=%s''', [etc]
```

Comment: Many thanks! That worked perfectly.  I found also that using single quotes for the statement and double quotes for the identifier worked.  E.g.,

Comment: df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM establishments_by_region Where "CD/CSD"=%s', engine, params=(province_selected,))

Comment: Yes, in that example, single quotes will do to quote the SQL.  You can also use double-quotes, and escape the embedded double-quotes with backslashes.  But triple-quoted SQL is nice because you can use double-quotes for identifiers and single-quotes for strings, and not have to escape anything.